# suprema of two Littlewood Polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, optimization

Suppose that
\begin{equation}
f(\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n e^{i\omega n}
\end{equation}
where $x_n \in \{-1,+1\}$ and $\omega \in (0,2\pi)$

Various results and conjectures are present in the literature about the value of the infinity norm of $f(\omega)$: 
\begin{equation}||f(\omega)||_{\infty}=\max\left\{|f(\omega)|,\omega \in (0,2\pi)\right\}\end{equation}

Suppose now that 
\begin{equation}
g(\omega)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}y_n e^{i\omega n}
\end{equation}
where again $y_n \in \{-1,+1\}$ and $\omega \in (0,2\pi)$

Is there some result about the relationship among $||f(\omega)||_{\infty}$ and $||g(\omega)||_{\infty}$, in particular  $||f(\omega)||_{\infty}\lessgtr||g(\omega)||_{\infty}$, given that the sequences $x_n,y_n$ are known?

Thank you